# MongoDB pipeline with geoNear does not prune based on distance

Tags: php, mongodb

I've got a pipeline based on a user coordinates

```
 $pipeline = [            
        [
            '$geoNear' => [
                'near' => [
                    'type' => 'Point',
                    'coordinates' => $coordinates
                ],
                'spherical' => true,
                'distanceField' => 'distance'
            ]    
        ],                        
        [
            '$redact' => [
                '$cond' => [
                    'if' => [
                        //100km
                        ['$lte' => ['$distance', 100]]
                    ],
                    'then' => '$$KEEP',
                    'else'=> '$$PRUNE'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        ['$sort' => ['distance' => 1]]      
];
```

when I aggregate with this pipeline, It returns a bunch of documents with a calculated distance, but documents with a distance > 100 km do not get pruned. I can see documents with a distance of 1460. What am I doing wrong ?

```
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "name" : "something",
    "distance" : 20
},
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "name" : "something else",
    "distance" : 1460
}
```

Comment: `$geoNear` have a `maxDistance` field that will solve your issue and will be more efficient to use...Also, please notice that `$geoNear` distance is in meters, not Km

Comment: You're right, I'd love to know why it's not working based on the calculated distance during redact... I just tried maxDistance and it does work.

Comment: It is working as expected on [the mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KYq1HOCScAh)